# Factorization of a two variable polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

I was wondering how would I factor the polynomial $x^{2}-3xy+3y^2$ for variables $x$ and $y$ over $\mathbb{C}$. I am aware that if you solve, say for $y$ you get $y=\frac{1}{6}(3x\pm i\sqrt{3}x)$. Thus it seems like the factorization will be of the form $(x-a)(x-b)$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$ (involving $y$ somewhere of course), but I am unsure how to proceed, since I cannot find a proper formula to use for this situation.

Comment: You might try palying around with $(x-ay)(x-by)$ and see what conditions this would impose on $a$ and $b.$

Comment: "*for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x,y>0$ over $\mathbb{C}$*" $\;-\;$ What is "*over $\mathbb C$*" supposed to mean? There is no order in $\,\mathbb C\,$ so it doesn't make sense to say that something is positive "*over $\,\mathbb C\,$*".

Comment: This is an unnecessary detail that I just removed.

Comment: For a homogeneous polynomial in $2$ variables, you can just dehomogenize (set $y=1$), factor, and then rehomogenize. So factor $x^2 - 3x + 3$ as $(x-a)(x-b)$ and then rehomogenize to obtain $(x-ay)(x-by)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $t:=\dfrac xy$ (for $y\ne0$). Then $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2=y^2(at^2+bt+c).$$

Now after factorization,

$$y^2(t-\alpha)(t-\beta)=(x-\alpha y)(x-\beta y).$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community The answer is reasonably clear to anyone who has a clue. The heuristics of the bot that posted the comment are less than clear, though ;-)